# Convert hour of the day and day of the week into datetime in C++

Tags: c++

If I have hour of the day and day of the week as 1am and Monday. How can I convert these into a datetime value in C++? thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jack

Comment: Have you looked at [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime)?

Comment: What is `datetime` in C++ ? I never heard about a standard class called `datetime`. Are you looking for something similar to C# `DateTime` ?

Answer (score 0):

may be this can help you:

[boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.time_math)

Answer (score 0):

2am on Sunday occurs at least once a week (twice when switching to/from daylight saving!).

So you need the month and day in that month.

Comment: thanks for your information. I am new to C++, just came from Delphi and C# a week ago. How to pass the monthly value to the month parameter? Does the following 
look ok?
 std::tm tm;
 tm.tm_wday = 1;
 tm.tm_hour = 1;
 tm.tm_month = 1;

And how do I compare this tm with current datetime? thanks very much

Comment: Use unix time - number of seconds since the epoch - Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Time in standard C/C++ can be represented with [std::tm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm)

> Structure holding a calendar date and time

```
std::tm tm;
tm.tm_wday = 1; // monday
tm.tm_hour = 1; // 1 am
```

**How to get local time ?**

```
#include <ctime>
...
time_t rawtime = time(&rawtime);
struct tm *tnow = localtime(&rawtime);
```

Maybe a simpler option would be to use C++11 [time_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) (must have compatible compiler)

```
system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
```

then go back to a tm object

```
std::tm* tnow = localtime(now);
```

Time difference

```
struct tm diff = difftime(mktime(&tnow),mktime(&tm);
```

Comment: std::tm tm;
tm.tm_wday = 1; // monday
tm.tm_hour = 1; // 1 am

Comment: thanks for your information. I am new to C++, just came from Delphi and C# a week ago. How to pass the monthly value to the month parameter? Does the following 
look ok?
 std::tm tm;
 tm.tm_wday = 1;
 tm.tm_hour = 1;
 tm.tm_month = 1;

And how do I compare this tm with current datetime? thanks very much

Comment: @JackyBi The way time is handled in C++ can be confusing. Take time to read the docs I pointed out and look at the examples.